# api.ai - duplicate intents

Tags: artificial-intelligence, agent, dialogflow-es

I'm having some troubles with intents on API.AI.

I have an intent -let’s call it intent01- aimed at managing any generic info request about some services (e.g. “I would like to know more about your services” and so on), which replies to the user explaining the services and asking him if he want to have more details about service1 or service2.
I than created 3 intents (intent01.1, intent01.2, intent01.3) in order to handle the possible user’s replies to intent1 (“I want to know more about service1”, “I want to know more about service2” or “no interest”), because each of them has to provide a different answer. They are linked to the father intent using the context.

I also wanted to manage a possible direct user’s question such as “I want to know more about service 1”, so I created a different intent (intent02), which provides exactly the same answer of intent01.1.

This solution doesn’t seem to be much scalable, do anyone know a best practice in order not to duplicate intents in such a situation?

Thank you for your time
Stefano

Comment: I add an additional example: I have 2 products (product1 and product 2) and I want the VA to be able to answer to any question about their tech details, cost and expiration.

I imagined several possible sequences of user's question that I would like to handle using the min number of intents possible, such as:

#Sequence 1:
-I want tech details about product 1
-What's its price?
-what about its exp. date?
#Sequence 2:
-What's the price of product2?
-I want to know tech details about product1
-What's its price? //referring to product1
and so on. How do you suggest to handle this?

Comment: Create 3 Intents, ProductAIntent, "i want to know about producta", create a "context" "ContextProductA" , ProductBIntent "Iwant to Know about ProductB" , Create COntext "ProductB". Third Intent is your generic Price, Expiration etc. which you can vary based on the context in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see [here](https://discuss.api.ai/t/intent-hieararchy-and-duplicates/4380/8?u=agrumiro) i think it resolves your issue. Regards

Comment: Thank you so much your idea perfectly fits with my issue!